# Handling hash with HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I am using the history.js plugin here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ for handling HTML5 History in my application. And I want to handle **both** HTML5 and HTML4 versions (using the hash fallback).

You can see the demo here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/

---

### Question 1

How do I load the correct content based on the hash when a person visits a url with a hash in (hasn't clicked a link on the website) As the server won't understand what the code is and I don't want to have to double the request by checking if the hash exists and then calling the content via AJAX. So for example: `http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#about.php` doesn't load in the about.php content.

**Update:**

I've seen some examples here: https://gist.github.com/balupton/858093 which seem to cover loading the correct content (even optimised versions). But I'm struggling to get it to work in combination with my HTML5 version.  View source: http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/ AND it only runs when a person clicks a link instead of on page load which is the original issue.

**Update 2:**

Tried an example here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/history4/#/contact.php to get the content to load in contact.php content using the snippet in the source but doesn't work...? BUT according to the article here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling#wiki-why-the-hashbang-is-unnecessary this code SHOULD be AJAX loading in the correct content if it has a hash on it. Any ideas why?

---

### Question 2

How do I force the `/#/` on the root and prefix all urls with `#/'

As currently if you try and visit a page via a link in a HTML4 browser, you end up with weird urls like:

`http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#contact.php` and `http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#./`

instead of:

`http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#/contact.php` and `http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#/`

---

And if I start on an inner page with:

`http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/contact.php` and choose a link then I end up with: `http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/contact.php#about.php` when what it should be is: `http://dev.driz.co.uk/history45/#/about.php`

Answer (score 3):

> How do I load the correct content based on the hash when a person visits a url with a hash in (hasn't clicked a link on the website) As the server won't understand what the code is

The server won't see the `#` or anything after it

> and I don't want to have to double the request by checking if the hash exists and then calling the content via AJAX.

Your only other option is to redirect (by setting `location` with JavaScript) to the URL that you would have used if the history API was available.

> How do I force the /#/ on the root?

You'd have to redirect to the homepage (again by setting `location`) if the history API isn't supported.

---

I take the view that if they are using a browser which doesn't support the history API (which probably means Windows XP and IE 8 these days) then they can get the non-Ajax fallbacks and I never have to deal with the hash hack.

Comment: I've updated with OP with some more examples of what I have tried to get question 1 working along with a test. But it's not loading in the content when doing the hash?

Comment: Also with regards to HTML5 support. The API isn't supported by IE until IE10.

Comment: @Cameron — Yes, but there are very few IE9 users since most of them get auto-updated. It is XP users who get stuck on IE8.

Comment: Unfortunately the client I am building this for is a University which is locked down to IE8 on 80% of their machines and IE9 for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to force all browsers (both HTML4/5) to use hashes, you'd use change the History.js Options within your init

```
History.options.html4Mode = true
```

However, you may also want to consider using the $.address functionality from jQuery which can append any new URL you want with a hash.

Also within the $.address method, you could also determine where to redirect the user based on their init URL if they were accessing the site for the first time:
Say, have a user access a URL with say
    http://www.site.com/#/about.php

you could then have a function which listens to any changes to any changes based on the URL changes

```
$.address.change(fn)
```

REF: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/

**UPDATE**

One thing I've discovered that may apply here is that if you have a click event handler which behaves by pushing a new state, even if you are currently on that same page, History js will append the same url to the end of the existing URL with a hash

e.g.
If on About Page (and your state is "about") and you click the about link - 
your URL will change from 
    http://www.site.com/about
to
    http://www.site.com/about#/about

To save yourself the hassle, have an if statement on that button that checks your History State for "about" and if not, pushState "About"

e.g.

```
$('.about.btn').on('click', function(e){
  if(History.getState().data.State != "About") {
    e.preventDefault();
    History.pushState({"State": "About"}, null, "/about"); 
  }
})
```

Comment: But how do you get a url like: `http://www.site.com/#/about.php` as mine are like: `http://www.site.com/#about.php` The docs show it as the former but it's the latter for me.

Comment: Also where in my code does that html4mode go? As I can't get it to work for mine.

Comment: **REF Comment 2**: **Where to put html4mode**

Sorry but I haven't been able to test the html4Mode yet (though I've tried it within my console terminal) - I believe you can init the html4Mode from your 

`document.ready()`

I'm not confident in saying that if you brought that declaration out of the document ready, that the option will still work.

Comment: **REF Comment 1:** **how to add "/" to your hash**

If you add `History.pushState(obj, titleString, "/"+about.php);`
This should work in your favour